# Unable to get token in chrome extension chrome with identity.getAuthToken

Tags: google-chrome-extension, oauth

I'm unable to get the auth token using

```
chrome.identity.getAuthToken({interactive: true}, token => {
...
}
```

I get this error:

```
Unchecked runtime.lastError: OAuth2 request failed: Connection failed (-2).
```

I set up an OAuth 2.0 Client for ChromeApp and specified the application id of my extension. Also set up a consent page.
My manifest looks like this:

```
  "permissions": [
    "storage",
    "identity"
  ],
  "key": "<my application key>",
  "oauth2": {
      "client_id": "<my client id>.apps.googleusercontent.com", 
      "scopes": [
          "openid", "email", "profile"
      ]
  }
```

How can I fix or at least debug this issue?

Comment: You have to use the correct [scopes](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes#oauth2): instead of `email`, you have to write `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email`, for example

Comment: @IvánNokonoko Thank you for the suggestion, but it doesn't work either, same error.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue and I noticed that I wasn't using Chrome in the first place, I was using Microsoft Edge.

Make sure you are using Chrome.